# Monitoring python shell glue jobs in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

In the AWS documentation, they specify how to activate monitoring for Spark jobs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-profile-glue-job-cloudwatch-metrics.html), but not python shell jobs.

Using the code as is gives me this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'`

Worse, after commenting out `from pyspark.context import SparkContext`, I then get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsglue.context'`. It seems the python shell jobs don't have access to glue context? Has anyone solved for this?

Answer (score 1):

The python shell jobs are purely python based environment and do not have access to pyspark ( EMR in the backend). You will not be able to get access to the context attribute here. That is purely a spark concept and glue is essentially a wrapper around pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting into glue python shell jobs more, and resolving some dependencies in some code files that are shared between my spark jobs and pyshell jobs.  I was able to resolve the pyspark dependency, by including in the creation of my .egg/.whl file, in requirements.txt, pyspark==2.4.7.  That version because another library required it.

You still cannot use the pyspark context as mentioned above by Emerson, because this is python runtime, not the spark runtime.

So when building distribution with setuptools, can have a requirements.txt that looks like this(below), and when the shell is setup, it will install these dependencies:

> elasticsearch 
> aws_requests_auth 
> pg8000 
> pyspark==2.4.7 
> awsglue-local